# Create new screen buffer with win32api in Python

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, pywin32

I want to draw a specific image to my second screen in Windows 7 using Python 3.4. I can get the handle and screen dimensions using pywin32 :

```
import win32api
screens = win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors()
```

I get the handles,dimensions of my screens:

```
[(<PyHANDLE:393217>, <PyHANDLE:0>, (0, 0, 1280, 720)),
(<PyHANDLE:7472233>, <PyHANDLE:0>, (1920, 0, 3360, 900))]
```

I thought of creating a new buffer with the dimensions of my screen , writing my data/image to the new buffer and setting it as the active screen.

I don't think I can do that with the pywin32 module and I though of accessing the Windows API through ctypes. But I cannot find the functions of the API like described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685032(v=vs.85).aspx

How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: You have linked to console functions which apply to a console windows text buffer - so no drawing or graphics.  Usually you would draw into a window you create, please clarify what you wish to achieve.

Comment: The accepted answer has little to do with your screen, per se. A console screen buffer is an output buffer for unicode text in the console window, limited to a palette of 16 colors for the text background and foreground. If you're looking to do text art, it would be simpler to use [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon), which hooks Windows API functions to support ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: I have since realized that the way I was going about it was wrong. I want to get control of the entire second screen, with no window or anything. I want to be able to draw a 8bit image on the screen , i.e. I want to specify a 8bit value for each pixel on the screen.
Note: The screen I am referring to is an instrument that connects to the computer via HDMI and is essentially a second screen expecting an image with a proper dimension.

Comment: Can I use DirectPython http://directpython11.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html to directly draw on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Can use the win32console module:

```
=> python
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:06:10) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import win32console
>>> help(win32console.CreateConsoleScreenBuffer)
Help on built-in function CreateConsoleScreenBuffer in module win32console:

CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(...)
    Creates a new console screen buffer
```